# How do I validate dynamically created controls in jquery at server side - Php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am creating an applicaiton where hundreds of controls are created dynamically in Jquery as below.

```
var $link='<a id="bucket'+data[0].ID+'" class="Initial" href="#"></i></a>';  
     $($btnGroupdiv).append($link);
```

While adding controls I am assigning unique ID to each control.

And this is how I am identifying each control while accessing it.

```
$(".Initial").click(function(){

 var $pid=this.id.replace("bucket","");
```

But here's the issue.

These IDs can be changed at browser with "Inspect Element" option.

**ServerSide Situation**

IDs which I have assigned to controls, are the primary keys of row in table called employee.

So changing ID at browser can temper data in a different row than intended.

How do I validate these controls at serverside, if ID is changed or not or How do I restore original ID of an element at server side??

I hope my question is clear enough.

Any help is apppreciated.

For everyone who thinks this is not possible.. I would ask - How does facebook or even StckOverflow do it??

Answer (score 0):

You need to define it differently for it to work with dynamic elements:

```
$(document).on("click", ".Initial", function(){
  var $pid=this.id.replace("bucket","");
  ...
});
```

It is impossible to detect if anybody has changed the ID via the browser.

Comment: How is this going to help with server side validation?

Comment: How does facebook or SO do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can't (software rule n°1: never trust user input).

What you can validate serverside is:

- Make sure the id exists
- Make sure the user has the rights to do the action on the data related to the id.

And this is it ! If a user is doing an action he is allowed to, on valid data, why should he be stopped to do so ?

Comment: User is allowed to do, but it changes the purpose of design. thats my only concern.

Comment: Well that's the thing with HTTP requests. As long as all the posted data is valid, you have no way to really know what actions happened client-side

Comment: how are they doing it in facebook or stackoverflow then? they are actually checking IDs, even if you change id and submit, it will changed back to original and then submit

Comment: could you provide an example ?

Comment: For ex: every like button on fb has unique ID, href, test-id etc attributes, even if you change all those attributes' value in browser, and hit like button, it will work and all original values will be restored. How does this happen? This is something I need to know.